# Consuming webservices in Javascript

Tags: javascript, web-services, webservice-client

I would like to consume my Axis2 webservice through a JavaScript client.

Answer (score 1):

You need a javascript SOAP client line [jQuery SOAP plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jqSOAPClient).

If you have access to the Web Service code, you could modify it to use JSON instead of SOAP.

Comment: What kind of service is then (JSON, XML, HTML)? In all these cases I recommend using a javascript framework like jQuery.